# Apply hashtable to object properties?

Tags: c#, wpf

After an extensive search, I ask here: is there a way to "apply" a hashtable to object properties?  For example, if I have a class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string PropertyOne {get;set;}
    public int PropertyTwo {get;set;}
}
```

Now, if I have a `Hashtable` of:

```
var table = new Hashtable {
    { "PropertyOne", "My string"},
    { "PropertyTwo", 4 }
};
```

Can I plug the table into an instance of the class so that Object.PropertyOne becomes "My string", etc, without having to parse it myself?

Comment: Maybe I'm just slow but I can't make any sense of this question. (truly I might just be slow)

Comment: Basically, if I make an empty instance of the class, is there a method or something I can use to plug the key:values in the hashtable into PropertyName:PropertyValue of the instance without doing it manually?

Comment: When you say "hashtable", do you mean a block of text? That looks like JSON without the surrounding `{ }`.

Comment: C# Hashtable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I see. Yes it it possible, but it's complicated. How are you populating the `Hashtable` in the first place?

Comment: I'm pulling data from a database into a hashtable with the keys as the column name and value as the field. This may be the wrong approach -- it's easy to use Dapper to pull from the DB as a model class that aligns with the table correctly, but what if the class has extra properties and such?

Comment: Basically, I want a class to pull itself from the database and apply the results to itself.

Comment: If the class has extra properties that the DB doesn't, then it'll just update the properties it can and everything else will be the default value (usually `null`). Mind you, I've never used Dapper. I have used Entity Framework and that's how that works. You might be better off asking a new question about Dapper to get that working rather than trying to go through a `Hashtable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are referring to is often referred to as a mixture between "auto-conversion" and "de-serialization". In this specific case it is most easily achieved via non-recursive reflection.

```
MyClass mine = new MyClass();
table.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
    .ToList()
    .ForEach((entry) => {
        var field = mine.GetType().getProperty((string)entry.Key);
        field.SetValue(mine, entry.Value);
    });
```

Comment: Please place it in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)